# Docker for Mac: Hostname setup for container

Tags: macos, networking, docker, docker-for-mac

Using Docker for Mac (v1.12.1) I'm running some containers via Compose. I'm using a simple docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  website:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "81:80"
```

From the host, connecting works fine via http://localhost:81.

To avoid the port mapping I would like to set up a hostname for the container so I can use something like http://mycontainer.local to connect from the host. Is it possible to set a hostname (or a static IP) for a container?

Answer (score 0):

[As suggested in this blog](https://blog.docker.com/2015/11/docker-multi-host-networking-ga/) you can connect using hostname 
" ContainerName.NetworkName " to your container.

Comment: Seems this requires a Linux host. With "Docker for Mac" I can't get this to work. In the meantime I found that it is not possible:
https://docker.github.io/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds